# solution to dynamical system with "xy" terms

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=xy-x\;(1), \quad \frac{dy}{d\tau}=-xy-\alpha-\beta\;(2)$

I'm preparing for my final in non-linear dynamics and I want to find the fixed points for this system i.e. when both equation (1) and (2) are equal to 0.

I see that I can factor equation (1) into
$\frac{dx}{d\tau}=x(y-1) \rightarrow x^*=0, y^*=1$

And the I understand that that using y=1 in (2) gives the fixed point $(\beta-\alpha,1)$.

But here comes my confusion when using x=0 in equation (2)
$0=-\alpha+\beta$ which is supposed to yield the second fixed point
$(0,\frac{\beta}{\alpha})$

I don't understand how the y can exist explicitly when x is equal to 0, maybe I am just lacking som basic mathematical skills.

Comment: The most probable explanation is that you made a mistake when copying (1) and (2). Are you sure about these?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write $$xy-x=0$$ and $$-xy-\alpha-\beta=0$$ Since we have $$xy=x$$ from the first equation we get $$-x-\alpha-\beta=0$$ so $$x=-\alpha-\beta$$

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. But I don't think I fully understand it still.
If I set x in the last equality to 0 how do I know that I obtain $y=\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$

Comment: In the case that $$x=0$$ then we get $$\beta=-\alpha$$

Comment: So far so good. But the second fixed point is supposed to be $(0,\frac{\alpha}{\beta})$ which I don't understand how I get from the result you present above

Comment: But $$y=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$$ fullfils our system only if $$-\alpha-\beta=0$$

Comment: I have checked it with Maple, and we get $$x=-\alpha-\beta,y=1$$ or $$x=0,\alpha=-\beta$$

Comment: Thanks again for the answer. 
So you are suggesting that the given solution to my exam problem is incorrect then?

Comment: Yes i think so.